# jsoup get elements inner text by selector

Tags: css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

I am seeking help here on using pattern for selector in jsoup
basically i am modifying someone else's code for my need

for example for href , it is done like this

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {
    // get the value from href attribute
    System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
    System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
}
```

I am referring here but not sure on which one to use
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

I want to find values like "Running map Tasks,1" and so on

```
<hr>
<h2>Cluster Summary (Heap Size is 555 MB/26.6 GB)</h2>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Running Map Tasks</th><th>Running Reduce Tasks</th><th>Total Submissions</th><th>Nodes</th><th>Occupied Map Slots</th><th>Occupied Reduce Slots</th><th>Reserved Map Slots</th><th>Reserved Reduce Slots</th><th>Map Task Capacity</th><th>Reduce Task Capacity</th><th>Avg. Tasks/Node</th><th>Blacklisted Nodes</th><th>Excluded Nodes</th><th>MapTask Prefetch Capacity</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>5576</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=active">8</a></td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>352</td><td>128</td><td>60.00</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=blacklisted">0</a></td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=excluded">0</a></td><td>0</td></tr></table>
<br>
<hr>
```

How can I get the text inside all  tags?

I should also look for header like "Cluster Summary" and so i can use  or  accordingly like this from my rest of URL

```
<h2 id="running_jobs">Running Jobs</h2>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<thead><tr><th><b>Jobid</b></th><th><b>Priority</b></th><th><b>User</b></th><th><b>Name</b></th><th><b>Start Time</b></th><th><b>Map % Complete</b></th><th><b>Current Map Slots</b></th><th><b>Failed MapAttempts</b></th><th><b>MapAttempt Time Avg/Max</b></th><th><b>Cumulative Map CPU</b></th><th><b>Current Map PMem</b></th><th><b>Reduce % Complete</b></th><th><b>Current Reduce Slots</b></th><th><b>FailedReduce Attempts</b></th><th><b>ReduceAttempt Time Avg/Max</b></th><th><b>Cumulative Reduce CPU</b></th><th><b>Current Reduce PMem</b></th></tr>
</thead><tbody><tr><td id="job_0"><a href="jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201502130313_1511&refresh=30">job_201502130313_1511</a></td><td id="priority_0">NORMAL</td><td id="user_0">vdeadmin</td><td id="name_0">streamjob1942665573586845283.jar</td><td>Fri Feb 13 17:00:17 PST 2015</td><td>0.00%<table border="1px" width="80px"><tr><td cellspacing="0" class="perc_nonfilled" width="100%"></td></tr></table></td><td><a href="jobtasks.jsp?jobid=job_201502130313_1511&type=map&pagenum=1&state=running">1</a></td><td>0</td><td>0sec/0sec</td><td>1hrs, 30mins, 4sec</td><td>703.48 MB</td><td>0.00%<table border="1px" width="80px"><tr><td cellspacing="0" class="perc_nonfilled" width="100%"></td></tr></table></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0sec/0sec</td><td>0sec</td><td> 0 KB</td></tr>
```

Updates/additions to the question
My URL will contain long HTML, and i should be able to search specific group wise. I mean my search should be for block by block...i dont want to find all tr th from html...but specific to one table and so
e.g. in below, i am trying to display results from id="running job" only and then for some other set. while doing that i should not get results from other part of html

```
<h2 id="running_jobs">Running Jobs</h2>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<thead><tr><th><b>Jobid</b></th><th><b>Priority</b></th><th><b>User</b></th><th><b>Name</b></th><th><b>Start Time</b></th><th><b>Map % Complete</b></th><th><b>Current Map Slots</b></th><th><b>Failed MapAttempts</b></th><th><b>MapAttempt Time Avg/Max</b></th><th><b>Cumulative Map CPU</b></th><th><b>Current Map PMem</b></th><th><b>Reduce % Complete</b></th><th><b>Current Reduce Slots</b></th><th><b>FailedReduce Attempts</b></th><th><b>ReduceAttempt Time Avg/Max</b></th><th><b>Cumulative Reduce CPU</b></th><th><b>Current Reduce PMem</b></th></tr>
</thead><tbody><tr><td id="job_0"><a href="jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201502130313_1511&refresh=30">job_201502130313_1511</a></td><td id="priority_0">NORMAL</td><td id="user_0">vdeadmin</td><td id="name_0">streamjob1942665573586845283.jar</td><td>Fri Feb 13 17:00:17 PST 2015</td><td>0.00%<table border="1px" width="80px"><tr><td cellspacing="0" class="perc_nonfilled" width="100%"></td></tr></table></td><td><a href="jobtasks.jsp?jobid=job_201502130313_1511&type=map&pagenum=1&state=running">1</a></td><td>0</td><td>0sec/0sec</td><td>1hrs, 30mins, 4sec</td><td>703.48 MB</td><td>0.00%<table border="1px" width="80px"><tr><td cellspacing="0" class="perc_nonfilled" width="100%"></td></tr></table></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0sec/0sec</td><td>0sec</td><td> 0 KB</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should know is what are CSS [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [how](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) to use it.
In your case to get the text inside all "tr th" tags you should use the following code:

```
Elements trThs = doc.select("tr th");
for(Element trTh : trThs)
    System.out.println("text : " + trTh.text());
```

Comment: No problem @itsavy, don't hesitate to vote up for the answer.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i find < h2 >Cluster Summary and then how to display related "Running Map Tasks","Running reduce Tasks",... next line 1,5576,..

Comment: To get <h2> content you should use the same code, just change the selector to "h2" (doc.select("h2")). In general I would strongly recommend you to read the tutorial. There is nothing difficult about CSS selectors and it would help you a lot to understand what are you doing.

Comment: i am going through css selector link, but not able to find anything that limits search for particular block. So i have updated the original question with details. please check